# isMethod does not work

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my content.blade.php

```
<form action="{{ route('home') }}" method="post">

                        <input class="input-text" type="text" name="name" value="Your Name *" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
                        <input class="input-text" type="text" name="email" value="Your E-mail *" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">
                        <textarea name="text" class="input-text text-area" cols="0" rows="0" onFocus="if(this.value==this.defaultValue)this.value='';" onBlur="if(this.value=='')this.value=this.defaultValue;">Your Message *</textarea>
                        <input class="input-btn" type="submit" value="send message">

                        {{ csrf_field() }}

                    </form>
```

That's my routes(web.php)

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'web'], function(){

Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', ['uses'=>'IndexController@execute', 'as'=>'home']);
Route::get('/page/{alias}', ['uses'=>'PageController@execute', 'as'=>'page']);

Route::auth();
```

});

And Finally here is my IndexController.php, method execute():

```
if($request->isMethod('post')){

        $messages = [

          'required' => "Поле :attribute обязательно к заполнению",
          'email' => "Поле :attribute должно соответствовать email адресу"

        ];
        $this->validate($request, [

            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'text' => 'required'

        ], $messages);

        dump($request);

    }
```

So, the problem is that `dump($request)` does not work, and I also tried to comment everything except `dump($request)`, and the result is the same. I think it just skips `if($request->isMethod('post'))` so that it returns that the method is not true, may be there is something wrong with token, I am not sure.

How to resolve this issue?

edit:
That's the code above if statement

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Page;
use App\Service;
use App\Portfolio;
use App\People;
use DB;

class IndexController extends Controller
{
    //

    public function execute(Request $request){
```

Comment: whats the error ?

Comment: Can you show the code for the rest of the controller method (or at least the code above the if statement)?

Comment: no error there. Just skips if statement in controller when I click the button in the form

Comment: which version of laravel you are using?

Comment: @Abhilash.k.p version 5.6,

Comment: @RossWilson done

Comment: try printing `$request->method()` just before if condition

Comment: Try this Route::match(['get', 'post'], '/', 'IndexController@execute')->name('home');

Comment: be sure, if your validation is failed then it will redirect to previous page

Comment: @rkj it prints "GET" method after clicking the button

Comment: it is always better to separate 'get' and 'post' request

Answer (score 0):

You should assign `$request` to somewhere first.

For example, if i have a `store` method and i have to use `Request $request` for grabbing the information, i should establish it first, so by establishing it my application will recognize what does the variable is retrieving, let me show you an example code:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $data = $request->all();
    $data['a'] = Input::get('a');
    $data['b'] = Input::get('b');
    $data['c'] = Input::get('c');
    $data['d'] = Input::get('d');
    $data['e'] = Input::get('e');
    Letters::create($data);
    return redirect::to('/');
}
```

Did you get it?

If not, here is an example with `isMethod`:

```
$method = $request->method();

if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
//
}
```

In your code i did not see the `$var = $request->method();` (or what you want it to be).